# 'Shoot' animation doesn't play in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get my character to shoot when pressing "P". I have created a trigger called shoot, and in the animator state machine, have got the shoot animation linking back and  forth to the idle animation. Regardless of what i have tried, the "shoot" animation refuses to play when pressing "p". My "run" parameter which contains the blend tree of animation from idle->run works flawlessly on pressing D or A, however, whenever i press P, doesnt want to shoot, just stays in idle form.  Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
Animator image

http://i60.tinypic.com/i6kq9t.png

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewSoldier : MonoBehaviour {

Animator animator;
bool Shoot;
float Running = 0.08f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //float Run;
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    float speed = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

    if (Input.GetKey ("d")) {

                    this.transform.Translate (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"), 0, Running);
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 90, 0);
                    animator.SetFloat ("Run", Mathf.Abs (speed));
            } 
    else if (Input.GetKey ("a")) 
            {

                    this.transform.Translate (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"), 0, Running);
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, -90, 0);
                    animator.SetFloat ("Run", Mathf.Abs (-(speed)));
            } 
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("p"))
            {

                    animator.SetBool("Shoot", true);
                    animator.SetTrigger ("Shoot");
            }

    else        
            {
                bool Shoot = false;
                animator.SetFloat ("Run", Mathf.Abs(speed));
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: the animator image link is not working

Answer (score 1):

what event did you set on your animation tree to go to the shooting animation? 
It can be a number of things:

- Your animation change is not set to an event;
- Your animation change is set to float and you are using a bool and trigger;
- If your animation change is a trigger, just user SetTrigger;
- Your animation change maybe is not set to go from Run to Shoot;
- Maybe your event change is not "Shoot" because you misclicked on a key and you did not notice;

If you could show us a print of the tree, would be nice. Also, i you are pressing a or d, it will not shoot

Comment: Hi Spike,

I have attached a screenshot of the animator:

http://i60.tinypic.com/i6kq9t.png

(low rep so cant post using stackoverflows feature). 

I am unable to spot the issue. At the moment I want my character to shoot when i press 'p' when he is simply idle. Once i can perfect that, then i can add the transitions of running etc.

Comment: Any one with an idea :(